# Save data <li> include <div> using localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to create LocalStorage data for My Folder Creation and I'm in the learning phase.

*Images for my folder creation*

[image]

In JSFiddle, i just can save 1 of 2 elements, `<li>` or `<div>` and in the first submit, the input value does'nt appear inside the div.

```js
var count = 1;
// make a function that returns the DOM with updated count
function getNewList() {
  let label = count++;
  var addFolder = '<li>' +
    '<div class="zf-folder" style="width: 232px;">' +
    '<div class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 50px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">' +
    '<div class="_sideFolder"></div>' +
    '<div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">' +
    '<div class="ellipsis">' +
    '<div class="_iconFolder">' +
    '<div class="_icon-col">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<a href="#folder' + label + '" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration: none;"></a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>';
  return addFolder;
}

// Lets save them using submit.
$(".submitButton").click(function() {
  var inputan = $("#input_nameFolder").val();
  $('.nav li:last').find('a').html(inputan).focus();
  document.getElementById("input_nameFolder").value = "";

  // update the result array
  var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("folderList"));
  if (result == null)
    result = [];

  result.push({
    folder: getNewList(),
    nameFolder: inputan
  });
  // save the new result array
  localStorage.setItem("folderList", JSON.stringify(result));

  // append the new li
  $(".nav").append($(getNewList())); // here i want display div include input value

});

// on init fill the ul
var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("folderList"));
if (result != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var item = result[i];
    debugger
    $(".nav").append($(getNewList()).html(item.folder)); // and i want display div include input value.
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input_nameFolder" name="nameFolder">
<input type="button" class="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="ADD">

<!-- Result goes here -->
<ul class="nav">
</ul>
```

[**MY JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xb89f4Ld/)

Comment: I am still trying to figure out the question your fiddle is not helping either, all I can get is that you are adding the folder names to `localStorage` on `ADD` button and on adding it shows the folder name under it, but when you reload the page and want to load the saved folder names from `localStorage` they don't show up ? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, before, I learned to save input value. then i learned to save div element. and now, i want to save them, i want the result display like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX8bs.png) .

Comment: i dont know how to call `div` and `input` in this code `$(".nav").append($(getNewList()).html(item.folder));`

Comment: cant using this code `$(".nav").append($(getNewList()).html(item.folder, item.nameFolder)); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

do reload the page twice in case you have stored the previous HTML in `localstorage` as it would have wrong HTML structure , I have added `localStorage.removeItem('folderList');` in the end of the fiddle script to clear the previously saved `HTML` **you should remove it when you will use in your script** or you can use the below code block provided rather than copying from the fiddle.

---

First of all your fiddle has wrong loading sequence for the scripts.

Coming to the issue you are appending the `HTML` every time you load from the `localStorage` and that would keep on appending the menus as many time you reload the page, as you said that you are learning so I would go ahead with the code for you to compare the changes with your script.

Rather than making things complex you should keep them simple, especially at the start when you are learning.

You are adding the folder name separately after getting the `HTML` whereas you can pass the name in the function `getNewList` to generate the `html` along with the folder name and in the loop you can append them see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/L0hrL919/) and the reference to the code below

```
var count = 1;

    // make a function that returns the DOM with updated count
    function getNewList(foldername) {
        let label = count++;
        var addFolder = '<li>' +
            '<div class="zf-folder" style="width: 232px;">' +
            '<div class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 50px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">' +
            '<div class="_sideFolder"></div>' +
            '<div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">' +
            '<div class="ellipsis">' +
            '<div class="_iconFolder">' +
            '<div class="_icon-col">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<a href="#folder' + label +
            '" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration: none;"><span class="hyperspan" style="width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0;">' +
            foldername + '</span></a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</li>';
        return addFolder;
    }


    $(".submitButton").click(function () {
        var inputan = $("#input_nameFolder").val();

        // update the result array
        var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("folderList"));

        if (result == null) {
            result = [];
        }

        let newfolderHTML = getNewList(inputan);

        result.push({
            folder: newfolderHTML
        });

        // save the new result array
        localStorage.setItem("folderList", JSON.stringify(result));

        // append the new li
        $(".nav").append(newfolderHTML); // i want include myDiv

        //clear input 
        $("#input_nameFolder").val('');
    });

    // on init fill the ul
    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("folderList"));
    if (result != null) {
        //get the nav reference in DOM
        let nav = $(".nav");

        //clear the html contents
        nav.html('');

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var item = result[i];
            nav.append(item.folder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is so coooll !!

Comment: :) glad i was able to help you out, do select the answer as correct one

Answer (score 0):

If I true understand you. I think, your problem is done. I am used OOP at the all my project. Please, try this.

```
/*
 * @params data 'object'
 * @date 01.12.2017
 * Create Template
 *
 */
 function getNewList(data) {
     var addFolder = '<li>' +
            '<div class="zf-folder" style="width: 232px;">' +
                '<div class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 50px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">' +
                    '<div class="_sideFolder"></div>' +
                    '<div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">' +
                        '<div class="ellipsis">' +
                            '<div class="_iconFolder">' +
                                '<div class="_icon-col">' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#folder' + data.id + '" data-toggle="tab" style="text- decoration: none;">' +
                                '<span class="hyperspan" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0;">'+ 
                                    data.value +
                                '</span>'
                            '</a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</li>';
  return addFolder;
 }

/*
* @params storageName 'string'
* @date 01.12.2017
* Get Storage
* It get storage according to parameter.
*
*/
function getStorage(storageName) {
    if(typeof storageName === 'string') {
        var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName));
            if (result == null)
                return result = [];
            else
                return result;
    }
}

/*
* @params storageName 'string', data 'object'
* @date 01.12.2017
* Get Storage
*
*/
function setStorage(storageName, data) {
    if(typeof storageName === 'string', Array.isArray(data)) {
        localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(data));
        return true;
    }
}

/*
* @params storage 'array', value 'any'
* @date 01.12.2017
* Create Data
*
*/
function createObject(storage, value) {
    if(Array.isArray(storage) && (value !== '' || value !== 'undefined' )) {
        var data = {
            id: storage.length,
            value: value
        }
        storage.push(data);
        return storage;
    }
}  

/*
* 
* @date 01.12.2017
* Clic Action
*
*/
$(".submitButton").click(function() {
    var elm = $("#input_nameFolder"),
        inputan = elm.val(),
        storageName = 'folderList',
        storage = getStorage(storageName),
        data = createObject(storage, inputan);

    var response = setStorage(storageName, data);

    if(response) {
        elm.val('');
        resultBind(storageName);
    }
});

/*
* @params storageName 'string'
* @date 01.12.2017
* Html Bind at Data
*/
function resultBind (storageName) {
    var result = getStorage(storageName);
    if (result != null) {
        for (var i in result) {
            var item = result[i];
            $(".nav").append(getNewList(item)); // i want include input result, 
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/yarkinucerler/udscsn6g/1/)